# Implementing LinkedList.java class to My Main Driver class to use the get and remove method?

Tags: java, linked-list, implements

I am currently doing a code that tries to implement a separate LinkedList.java class to my main driver class.

After doing that I will then show the output and ask the user to remove one of the elements stored inside the linkedlist and then show the output again showing the changes.

**Question
How Do I implement or use the LinkedList.Java with my main driver class to get and then use the remove method ? Do I still have to use the add method?
I just don't know How the format would look like. Tried copy pasting the LinkedList class but I get an error.**

Here is my code:

```css
import java.util.Scanner;    
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class TestingCode {

   //private List<HawaiiNativeForestBirds> listofBirds = new LinkedList<HawaiiNativeForestBirds>();
   //private String database = new String("birds3.csv");
/**
* The main method starts the program
*
*@param args is the input file
   */
      

 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   //error checking for commandline input
      if(args.length != 1){
         System.out.println("Please enter at least one input file into the argument.");
         //terminates the program if more than 1 is entered
         System.exit(1);
      }
   
   
      String csvFile = args[0];
      String line = "";
      String cvsSplitBy = ",";
   
      
   
      List<HawaiiNativeForestBirds>  listofBirds = new LinkedList<HawaiiNativeForestBirds>();
      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
      
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         
            // use comma as separator
            String[] bird = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            HawaiiNativeForestBirds Hawaiinbird= new HawaiiNativeForestBirds(bird[0],bird[1],bird[2],Integer.valueOf(bird[3]));
            listofBirds.add(Hawaiinbird);
            
         }
      
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   // Display the actual values
      HawaiiNativeForestBirds[]  hbirds=new        HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()]; 
      int i=0;        
      hbirds= listofBirds.toArray(new HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()]);
      System.out.println("Display HawaiiNativeForestBirds linked list after adding objects from the input file into a linked list:");
      System.out.println("index   " + "name   "+ "   Scientific Name     "+ "        Color     " +       "      Population");        
      i=0;
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirds hbird:hbirds){
         i++;
         System.out.println(i+"   "+hbird.toString());
      }
   
   //remove method that asks the user for input on which row to delete
   
   // get user input
      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
         String input;
         int num;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         while (( input = br.readLine())  != null){ 
         
            System.out.print("Enter the row number of the item you wish to delete: ");
            num=sc.nextInt();
            if (num <= 0) {
               System.out.println("ERROR: The row number cannot be negative or zero.");
            }
            // check for row number too big
            else if (num > listofBirds.size() + 1) {
               System.out.println("ERROR: The row number is too big for the list.");
            } 
            
            else {
               for(int x=0;x<num;i++)   {
                  
                  listofBirds.delete(num);  
               }//for
            }//else
         }//while
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   
         
   // Display values again with the deleted row of data
             
      hbirds= listofBirds.toArray(new HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()]);
      System.out.println("Display HawaiiNativeForestBirds linked list after deleting a row of objects from the linked list:");
      System.out.println("index   " + "name   "+ "   Scientific Name     "+ "        Color     " +       "      Population");        
      i=0;
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirds hbird:hbirds){
         i++;
         System.out.println(i+"   "+hbird.toString());
      }
   
   
   } // end of main 
} //end of class 

/**
   * Class HawaiianNativeForestBirds stores and displays the data for each HawaiianTheme object
   * 
   * 
   */
  
 
class HawaiiNativeForestBirds {
   private String name;
   private String scientificname;
   private String color;
   private Integer population;
   public HawaiiNativeForestBirds(){
   
   }
   //constructor - used to initialize the four data fields
      /**
   * Stores the name,scientific name, color and population of the Hawaiian Birds
    *  
    * 
    * @param name is the name of the birds from the linked list
    * @param scientificname is the scientific name of the birds in the linked list
    * @param color is the color of each of the birds in the linked list
    * @param population is the total number of birds in the linked list   
    */

   public HawaiiNativeForestBirds(String name, String scientificname,
        String color, Integer population) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.scientificname = scientificname;
      this.color = color;
      this.population = population;
   }  
/**
    * Gets each bird's name
    * 
    * @return the birds name
    */


   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
    /**
    * Sets each birds name
    * 
    * @param name is the bird's name
    */

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   /**
    * Gets the bird's scientific name
    * 
    * @return the bird's scientific name
    */

   public String getScientificname() {
      return scientificname;
   }
    /**
    * Sets the birds scientific name
    * 
    * @param scientificname is the bird's scientific name
    */

   public void setScientificname(String scientificname) {
      this.scientificname = scientificname;
   }
   /**
    * Gets the bird's color
    * 
    * @return the bird's color
    */

   public String getColor() {
      return color;
   }
    /**
    * Sets the bird's color
    * 
    * @param color is the bird's color
    */

   public void setColor(String color) {
      this.color = color;
   }
   /**
    * Gets the bird's population
    * 
    * @return total population of the bird
    */

   public Integer getPopulation() {
      return population;
   }
    /**
    * Sets the bird's population
    * 
    * @param population is the total population of the bird
    */

   public void setPopulation(Integer population) {
      this.population = population;
   }
  /**
    * Display the output 
    * 
    * @return the name, scientificname, color, and population of the bird
    */

   public String toString() {
      String output = name +"     "+      scientificname + "             "+ color +"           "+        population;
      return output;
   }//end of toString 
           
}// end of class
```

***Here are my LinkedList.java, ListInterface.java, Node.Java and ListException.java that I will be trying to implement to my main driver which are all separate.***

```css
public class LinkedList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {

 // reference to first node in the linked list (linked nodes)
   protected Node<T> head = null;
 // Total number of items, which is used
 // for error checking and node removal.
   protected Integer size = new Integer(0);

   public LinkedList() {
    // no code, because data fields already initialized
   }

 /**
  * Adds an item (of any class) to the end of the list
  * 
  * @param item
  *            is the object that is added to the list
  */
   public void add(T item) {
    // case 1: if empty list
      if (head == null) {
       // list is empty, so add to beginning of list
       // make new node and assign to head of list
         head = new Node<T>(item, null);
      }
      // if not empty list
      else {
       // case2: add to end of list
       // current starts at 2nd node in list
         Node<T> previous = head;
         Node<T> current = head.getNext();
       // while not at end of list
         while (current != null) {
          // advance to next node
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
         }
       // Add new node to end of list:
       // Make new node that has "null" for next.
       // A node with "null" is always the last node
         Node<T> node = new Node<T>(item, null);
       // Point previous node (last node) to new node
         previous.setNext(node);
      }
    // increase size of list
      size++;
   }

 /**
  * Gets an item (address to an item) from any position in the list.
  * 
  * @param position
  *            The position of an item in the list.
  * @returns the address to the requested item
  * @exception ListException
  *                if an item does not exist at that position
  */
   public T get(Integer position) throws ListException {
    // check if empty list
      if (head == null) {
         throw new ListException("Cannot get an item from an empty list!");
      }
    // if position is outside range, throw exception
      if (position < 1 || position > size) {
         throw new ListException(position + " is outside list range!");
      }
    // Find node:
    // counter to keep track of loops
      Integer counter = new Integer(1);
    // point to current node
      Node<T> current = head;
      while (!counter.equals(position)) {
       // BAD CODE: while(counter != position){
       // goto next node for current pointer
         current = current.getNext();
       // add 1 to counter
         counter++;
      }
    // return the data (item) stored by the node
      return current.getData();
   }

 /**
  * Removes an item at any position from the list.
  * 
  * @param position
  *            The position of an item in the list.
  * @exception ListException
  *                if an item does not exist at that position
  */
   public void remove(Integer position) throws ListException {
    // check if empty list
      if (head == null) {
         throw new ListException("cannot remove from empty list");
      }
    // if position is outside range, throw exception
      if (position < 1 || position > size) {
         throw new ListException(position + " is outside list range.");
      }
    // if at beginning of list
      if (position.equals(1)) {
       // remove 1st node
         head = head.getNext();
      }
      // if not at beginning of list
      else {
       // Find node:
       // point previous to 1st node
         Node<T> previous = head;
       // point current to 2nd node
         Node<T> current = head.getNext();
       // loop position-2 number of times
         for (int i = 2; i < position; i++) {
          // goto next node for previous and current
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
         }
       // Point the previous node to node after current node.
       // This "skips" over one node, thus removing it!
         previous.setNext(current.getNext());
      }
    // decrease size of list
      size--;
   }

 /**
  * Automatically called by println() or print()
  * 
  * @return a String of the List in CSV (comma separated values) format
  */
   public String toString() {
    // instantiate empty string
      String csvFormat = new String("");
    // display position of each item to user
      Integer position = new Integer(1);
    // loop through all the nodes in linked list
      for (Node<T> current = head; current != null; current = current
        .getNext()) {
       // keep adding to end of string
         csvFormat = csvFormat + position + ", " + current.toString() + "\n";
       // add one to position for each loop
         position++;
      }
      return csvFormat;
   }

 /**
  * This Is An "Accessor" Method - Used To Get A Data Field.
  * 
  * @return the size of the list
  */
   public Integer getSize() {
      return size;
   }

}// end of class
```

```css
public interface ListInterface<T> {

 /**
  * Adds an item (of any class) to the list
  * 
  * @param item
  *            is the object that is added to the list
  */
   public void add(T item);

 /**
  * Gets an item (address to an item) from the list.
  * 
  * @param position
  *            The position of an item in the list.
  * @returns the address to the requested item
  * @exception ListException
  *                if an item does not exist at that position
  */
   public T get(Integer position) throws ListException;

 /**
  * Removes an item from a list.
  * 
  * @param position
  *            The position of an item in the list.
  * @exception ListException
  *                if an item does not exist at that position
  */
   public void remove(Integer position) throws ListException;

 /**
  * This Is An "Accessor" Method - Used To Get A Data Field.
  * 
  * @return the size of the list
  */
   public Integer getSize();

}// end of interface
```

```css
public class Node<T> {

 // data fields (reference variables)
 // data stores an object of any class
   private T data;
 // next points to the next node
   private Node<T> next;

 /**
  * Constructor - Used To Create EAch Object & Initialize DAta Fields.
  * 
  * @param data2
  *            initializes the data reference variable.
  * @param next2
  *            initializes the next reference variable..
  */
   public Node(T data2, Node<T> next2) {
      data = data2;
      next = next2;
   }

 /**
  * Used to Display The Data Stored In EAch Node.
  * 
  * @return a String for the data
  */
   public String toString() {
      return data.toString();
   }

 /**
  * This Is An "Accessor" Method - Used To Get A Data Field.
  * 
  * @return the data
  */
   public T getData() {
      return data;
   }

 /**
  * This Is An "Accessor" Method - Used To Get A Data Field.
  * 
  * @return the address to the next node
  */
   public Node<T> getNext() {
      return next;
   }

 /**
  * This Is A "Mutator" Method - Used To Set A Data Field.
  * 
  * @param data2
  *            is a pointer to an object.
  */
   public void setData(T data2) {
      data = data2;
   }

 /**
  * This Is A "Mutator" Method - Used To Set A Data Field.
  * 
  * @param next2
  *            is a pointer to the next node.
  */
   public void setNext(Node<T> next2) {
      next = next2;
   }


} // end of class
```

```css
public class ListException extends RuntimeException {
 /**
  * @param message
  *            describes the exact cause of the error.
  */
   public ListException(String message) {
      super(message);
   }// end of constructor
}// end of class
```

Hopefully someone can help me out on this :(